# Virtual fields and using HAVING in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I need to find those rows from mysql which have unique `test` field. I tried to add virtualFields to get the count of `test` then I grouped by `test` field and checked that test must be equal to 1.

Following is my code... it gives error: `Syntax error or access violation`

```
public function index()
{
    $this -> User -> virtualFields(array(
        'countTest' => "COUNT(User.test)"
    ));

    $users = $this -> User -> find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('countTest' => 1),
        'group' => 'User.test'
    )); 

    pr($users); die;
}
```

I found the MySql query which solves the problem : `'SELECT test, COUNT(*) as count FROM users GROUP BY test HAVING COUNT(*) = 1';`

Can you convert the above query in CakePHP format.

Comment: Note that 'virtualFields' is not a *method*, it's a *property* of the Model; To add a virtual Field, use this: `$this->User->virtualFields = array('countTest' => 'COUNT(User.test)');`. Read the documentation here: [Virtual fields](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html). However, to use it as a `HAVING` condition is a bit tricky in CakePHP, it has to be appended to the 'GROUP BY' clause. see the 'group' key in the answer that @icebreaker provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this could lead you to right solution

```
$this->User->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array('User.test', 'COUNT(User.test) AS User__test_count'),
    'group' => array('User.test'),
    // or even cake style SQL injection :)
    // 'group' => array('User.test HAVING COUNT(*) = 1')
  ));
```